# wso2 call mediator returning the same response format in soap 11 for 3 different endpoints which have 3 different formats ( xml , soap 11,soap 12)?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, endpoint, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-integration-studio

[image: message builders][image: my message formattersmy message builders]

when trying to access the response nodes after a call mediator using xpath properties it did not work for two of the endpoints  supposed to return xml and soap 12 .. it only worked for the endpoint which returned a soap 11 response .
then i realized that all 3 endpoints had the same response format(soap 11) which is not the same as when calling the endpoints from postman.
i tried to add messageType and ContentType properties before the call mediator with different values to handle the response but still it did not work.
the log i got when i used  .
body = <soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
but in the actual response the soap envelope version is :"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope".
i am using wso2 micro-integrator v4.1.0 and integration studio v8.1.0

Comment: i was able to solve the issue by adding <messageBuilder contentType="text/xml" class="org.apache.axis2.builder.ApplicationXMLBuilder"/> to axis2.xml file